# clarity filter does not work with multiple values

Tags: filter, vmware-clarity

Clarity Filter doesn't work with multiple values on random search
Please find an attachment

[Filter Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8p8T.png)

Regards,
Rupali Jain

Comment: I don't know what you are asking here, can you show a demo with a StackBlitz? https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team

Comment: HI @JeremyWilken,  Please find attachment.

Answer (score 0):

The default built-in string filter is a simple string matcher, and that is explained in the documentation. For something more complex, you have to build this yourself with a custom filter. Often I have seen people build a custom filter with a list of checkboxes for the values in the field (such as `none`, `data`, etc) that can be applied in a search. See the custom filter documentation for details and demo of how to build your own.

https://v1.clarity.design/datagrid/custom-filtering